# Issue while passing array to setData() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I am trying to create a Pie Chart where I can switch from two data series with a button.

Everything works fine when I pass values directly to the `setData()` function on my button onclick event. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rjg30pc/2/) (working).

But if I save my datas in arrays, when I use setData(), the function overwrites the first array with the second. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rjg30pc/3/) (not working).

To sum up, when I use data directly it works :

```
// the button action
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        bool_pie = !bool_pie;
        if(!bool_pie){
            chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0]);
        }else{
            chart.series[0].setData([29.9, 71.5, 106.4]); 
        }
    });
```

But when I use variables, array `data1` is overwritten by array `data2`

```
    var data1 = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4];
    var data2 = [129.2, 144.0, 176.0];
// the button action
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        bool_pie = !bool_pie;
        if(!bool_pie){
            chart.series[0].setData(data2);
        }else{
            chart.series[0].setData(data1); 
        }
    });
```

I have therefore identified the issue, but I can't figure out how to manage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found your issue. When you pass `data1` to the highcharts initialization, you are passing a reference to that `data1`, which gets converted to an array of objects by highcharts. You have to pass a copy of that array in order to have `data1` and `data2` as arrays:

```
$(function () {
    var data1 = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4];
    var data2 = [129.2, 144.0, 176.0];
    var bool_pie = true;
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        series: [{
            data: data1.slice(0, data1.length)
        }]
    });

    // the button action
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        bool_pie = !bool_pie;
        var data = (!bool_pie) ? data2 : data1;
        chart.series[0].setData(data); //PASSING ARRAY VARIABLE
    });
});
```

I've modified the following line: `data: data1.slice(0, data1.length)`

http://jsfiddle.net/8rjg30pc/4/

Comment: Thanks, your solution works ! Weird behavior from Highcharts.

Comment: By the way, what is the point to use `data1.slice(0,data1.length)` if I can use `data1.slice()` ? Is it faster or something ?

Comment: `data1.slice()` will return a full copy of `data1`? if yes, than it will be faster and more readable :)